# Understanding C++ std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, reference-counting

I have a question, please go through the following simple C++ program,

```
int main( )
{
 shared_ptr<int> sptr1( new int );
 shared_ptr<int> sptr2 = sptr1;
 shared_ptr<int> sptr3;
 shared_ptr<int> sptr4;
 sptr3 = sptr2;

 cout<<sptr1.use_count()<<endl;
 cout<<sptr2.use_count()<<endl;
 cout<<sptr3.use_count()<<endl;

 sptr4 = sptr2;

 cout<<sptr1.use_count()<<endl;
 cout<<sptr2.use_count()<<endl;
 cout<<sptr3.use_count()<<endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3
3
3
4
4
4
```

How does `sptr1` and `sptr3` objects know reference count is incremented as it prints 4.

As far as I know reference count is a variable in each `shared_ptr` object.

Comment: Vittorio's answer is perfect, but it's worth stepping back a moment and asking yourself: would the reference count you described actually count the number of references? If not, what use would it be, and why would anyone write a smart pointer with that feature?

Comment: _"As far as I know reference count is a variable in each `shared_ptr` object."_ How could that possibly work? If each object didn't know when you make a copy of the _other_ objects, the reference counts would be meaningless.

Comment: There is nothing version specific in this question - or even standard specific, the same question about the `shared_ptr` in boost would have the exact same answer. It's a *general question about owning smart pointers with reference counted ownership*.

Comment: @JonathanWakely In fairness to the OP, they realise this, hence the question

Comment: A better question might be: why are all three reference counts the same? Once you've answered that, your question answers itself

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> As far as i know reference count is a variable in each shared_ptr object.

No, the reference count is stored in a "control block" on the heap. Every `shared_ptr` instance points to the same "control block" and keeps it alive (until all instances and all `weak_ptr` instances that share ownership with them are dead).

Comment: until all instances **and all `weak_ptr` instances that share ownership with them** are dead

Answer (score 0):

A `shared_ptr<T>` is usually implemented as two pointers.  One to the object data, and one to a structure that looks like this:

```
[strong reference count]
[weak reference count]
[type-erased destroyer fptr]
[type-erased destroyer data]
```

where the `[object ptr]` points to the actual object.

When you copy a `shared_ptr`, it creates another pointer to the above data (and to the actual object) and increments the `[strong reference count]` part of it.  Weak pointers behave similarly, but instead increase the `[weak reference count]` (when strong is 0 and weak is non-zero- the type-erased destroyer is called but the control block remains).

As an aside, when you call `make_shared` it does:

```
[strong reference count]
[weak reference count]
[type-erased destroyer fptr]
[object data]
```

where the pointer-to-object now points to the to the `[object data]` at the end of the control block.  This reduces the number of allocations to one.

A separate data and control block pointer is needed because of features like the fact that a shared_ptr to derived can be changed to a shared_ptr to base; that requires an adjustment to the pointer value in many cases.  Similarly, the aliasing constructor of shared ptr allows the control block and the pointed to object to be completely unrelated.

Taken from @Estinox's answer-that-isn't-an-answer, here is a [Channel9 talk](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/CPP/C-PP-Con-2014/Lightning-Talks-Anatomy-of-A-Smart-Pointer?term=smart%20pointer&lang-en=true) on how shared ptr works.

Comment: "_another copy to the above data_" unclear; what "above data"?

Comment: @curiousguy reworded